# How can I cut an element of a list in Python

Tags: python

I've got a txt file(answer.txt), and I read all the lines into a list, one line is one element. And this lines look like:

```
'ABC3 ASLS43'
```

and I'd like to cut it like:

```
'ABC3'
'ASLS43'
```

Do you have any idea about it? I think It has a simple answer, but I'm a beginner, and I couldn't find anything 'bout it.

The code:

```
person=[]
with open('answer.txt', 'r') as v:
    ps=sum(1 for line in open('answer.txt'))
    print(ps)
    for i in range(0, ps):
        person.append(v.readline().strip()) #read line by line
```

Comment: Is the "blockquote" part actually a part of it? And, you just want to split the line of spaces?

Comment: `"ABC3 ASLS43".split()`

Comment: You mean you want to split each line on the space?

Comment: `"ABC3 ASLS43".replace(' ', '\n')`

Comment: Yeah, but where will .split() split it? At the space?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the split() function. Try:

`your_string.split()`

Comment: split will split on whitespace by default, no param is required, can be simply strip()

Answer (score 1):

You can use [split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split the string on spaces, and change [append()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html?#array.array.append) for [extend()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html?#array.array.extend) which will append each element in the provided list.

```
person=[]
with open('answer.txt', 'r') as v:
    line = v.readline()
    while line:
        person.extend(line.strip().split())
        line = v.readline()
```

Comment: With this, the list will look like: person=[['ABC3 ASLS43'], /.../], but I would like it like: person=[ABC3, ASLS43]

Comment: No, it will look like `person=['ABC3','ASLS43',...]`. I am using `split()` which returns a list (splits the string at the space), and `extend()` takes a list and adds each element to `person`.

Comment: You are looping through the file twice though. You do not have to do that just to count the lines.

Comment: I used OP's code, but updated the array modification. My answer relates to the last line in this sample. I will update.